# How to make the azure app service trust the certificates issued by the OnPrem CA?

Tags: azure, web-services, ssl

I am trying to consume an onprem webservice from Azure APP service under https protocol. While I do I received the error

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure

This is meaningful, as Azure by default don't have to trust the service, presenting certificate issued by the OnPrem CA. However, Is there a way to configure the  trust in app service.

I tried uploading the public key certificate .cer file in Base encoded format and updated the app setting with the app key WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES as specified int he below article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/certificates

It dint work well and I get he same error. Is my understanding right/ Is thee a right way to do it.

Comment: are you doing cert based authentication ?

Comment: HI @Aravind, We are not intended to do  any certificate based authentication using client certificates. Thisis to add server's public certificate to trust the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed to upload the Intermediate CA's public certificate, as intermediate CA has issued the certificate for the on prem service.

After I have added, I have changed the appkey WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES to hold the thumbprint of both root CA's and intermediate CA's certificate comma separated.
That enabled the communication.

Comment: Can you explain more on how you did this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score -2):

Consider [Azure Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) which enables you to connect your Azure App Services (including Azure Functions) to existing on-prem services/APIs.

Sample and case study can be found here : https://azuregems.io/azure-hybrid-connections/

Comment: That would be overkill for the purpose of trusting an internal CA cert, and wouldn't even solve the problem anyway.